# facebook app for multi tabs

Tags: facebook

I have a e-commerce app for Facebook.

The think is that I want to have 2 tabs in the fan page that load the e-commerce app, one app for men clothes and the other one for woman.

The problem is that I can't distingue between tabs, the only posible solution that I see is to create two diferents facebook apps, the problem is that if an user want to see both tabs have to accept the app two times.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the same app can't be installed twice onto the same page as a tab.

A possible workaround is to have one or both of the tabs be a basic app with mostly static content, and have it redirect to the actual store

Answer (score 0):

you can also get 
1 .first a  page-sign request 
2. then using graph api get the user gender and display data .

Comment: They specifically asked if the same app ID could be used for two different tabs